# Is it possible to let a group have multiple parent groups in gitlab?

Tags: permissions, gitlab

The gitlab in my company has the following group and project relationship:

```
Product1 / FrontEnd / project1
                    / project2
         / BackEnd  / project3
                    / project4
                    / project5
```

Now we have new groups that are named based on our departments. (Department1, Department2, Department3, ...)

I wish that users of `Department1` group can access the projects under `BackEnd` group.

One way to do this is go to project3, project4, and project5's pages and click "Settings -> Members -> Invite group" to invite `Department1` group.

The drawback of this method is that when the number of projects under `BackEnd` is large, we have to repeat the same inviting process on all the projects under `BackEnd`. This is very inconvenient.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to "invite group" from `BackEnd` group. By doing so, we can have users under `Department1` to share the permissions of `BackEnd`.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, do you mean something like this? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/#share-a-group-with-another-group

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you for your information. My gitlab version is too old. I need to upgrade before using this feature.